# Input value invisible when set with php

Tags: php, html, mysql, input

**PHP**

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH)){
  echo "<tr>";
  for($i=0;$i<7;$i++){
    if($i==0){
      echo "<td><input type='text' val='$row[$i]' /></td>";
    }
    if($i>1){
      echo "<td>$row[$i]</td>";
  }}echo "</tr>";
}
```

Except for the first column, which contains the `input` tag, everything comes out fine.  The input tag shows up, but it appears empty--nothing to see, nothing to highlight. If I do 'inspect element', however, I see it has the correct value according to the output from the queried table.

Any thoughts as to what causes this strange behavior and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use basic HTML Tag

You have to use **"value" instead of "val"**

See the Basic HTML Tag

```
<input type="text" value="Nikunj"/>
```

Comment: Oops! I've been working too heavily with jQuery lately, I forgot how to write straight HTML tag!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `value` attribute instead of `val`:

```
echo "<td><input type='text' val='$row[$i]' /></td>";
-----------------------------^
```

should be:

```
echo "<td><input type='text' value='$row[$i]' /></td>";
-----------------------------^
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `val` to `value`. `val` is not a valid attribute.

```
<input type='text' val='$row[$i]' />
--------------------^
```